# How to only perform LTS upgrades?

Tags: update-manager, lts

I know I've seen this documented somewhere before, but what's the option to keep update-manager from prompting for updates except for LTS-to-LTS releases?

Answer (score 20):

If you go to Ubuntu > System > Administration > Update Manager, you'll see a Settings... button at the bottom left of the dialog. In the dialog, switch to the Updates tab and uncheck the updates checkboxes and set Release Upgrade to "Long Term Support Releases Only".

It should look something like:

[image]

See the [community docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Updates_Tab) for more information.

Comment: The given picture is misleading: "Release upgrade" is set to "Normal Releases", where it should be "LTS Releases"

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the GUI? I have an Ubuntu VPS that keeps pestering me to upgrade to 12.10.

Comment: @dgw You'll probably want to check out /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades. You can set Prompt to lts instead of normal and that should help. Run 'do-release-upgrade' to check if it finds a new release.

Answer (score 20):

Posting as an answer what @flickerfly said in a comment: the way to do it without a GUI is to change the value of `Prompt` in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`.

```
[DEFAULT]
Prompt=lts
```

The possible values are (copied from the file itself):

- `never`: Never check for a new release.
- `normal`: Check to see if a new release is available.  If more than one new
  release is found, the release upgrader will attempt to upgrade to
  the release that immediately succeeds the currently-running
  release.
- `lts`: Check to see if a new LTS release is available.  The upgrader
  will attempt to upgrade to the first LTS release available after
  the currently-running one.  Note that this option should not be
  used if the currently-running release is not itself an LTS
  release, since in that case the upgrader won't be able to
  determine if a newer release is available.

Comment: Why can't the non-LTS updater determine when there is a new LTS version available?

Comment: Thanks, this works for running the update in the terminal via ̣´sudo do-release-upgrade´