# Why is there "no new release found" during do-release-upgrade when using an intermediary TLS termination proxy?

Tags: do-release-upgrade

The question best matching my situation is described here:

[do-release-upgrade failing on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - says: No new release found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205332/do-release-upgrade-failing-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts-says-no-new-release-found)

... and questions linked therein; I'd have replied to one of those as an "alternative answer", but my SE rep is insufficient.

---

In rare cases, the issue stems from a [TLS termination proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_termination_proxy) being used, a fact that may be obscured from a particular VPS sysadmin, or out of reach to configure.

The issue manifests as follows:

```sh
% do-release-upgrade -c
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS develoment release 
set Prompt=normal in /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.
```

However, retrieving the file manually works, e.g. on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS:

```sh
% curl -s https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts | grep -A10 focal
Dist: focal
Name: Focal Fossa
Version: 20.04.2 LTS
Date: Thu, 23 April 2020 20:04:00 UTC
Supported: 1
Description: This is the 20.04.2 LTS release
Release-File: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/Release
ReleaseNotes: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement
ReleaseNotesHtml: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement.html
UpgradeTool: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/focal.tar.gz
UpgradeToolSignature: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/focal.tar.gz.gpg
```

`do-release-upgrade` is written in Python using `urllib`, its `urlopen` is tripping up for some reason, and I can't determine why.

Answer (score 2):

I've started with enabling debug mode:

```sh
% export DEBUG_UPDATE_MANAGER=yesplz
% do-release-upgrade -c
```

... and finding the following in the output:

```
...
result of meta-release download: '<urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 403 SSL CONNECT proxying not configured>'
...
```

The first work-around I've tried is changing the URL in file `/etc/update-manager/meta-release` to have `http://` instead of `https://`. This "works", but not something to take lightly.

I've also tried installing `squid` (a caching proxy) on the same machine and setting environment variables `http[s]_proxy` (lowercase and uppercase), guessing that an extra layer of software may cargo-cult releases into becoming reachable; but that didn't work (i.e. same error).

The last workaround - which works! - is downloading the file manually:

```sh
% curl https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts -o /home/`whoami`/.cache/update-manager-core/meta-release-lts
% sudo curl https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts -o /var/lib/update-manager/meta-release-lts
```

... and then forcing this file to be used, by editing `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py` and inserting at line 339, before an `urlopen()` attempt is made:

```py
print('UGLY: urlopen my XSS! >:(')
raise(HTTPError(code=304, url='', msg='', hdrs='', fp=open('/tmp/myXSS', 'w')))
```

---

So, to answer my own question, this is likely because of:

- the particular TLS terminating proxy configuration (that I don't have control over); or
- Python's `urllib`'s `urlopen` not picking up the proxy settings, or the settings being incorrect (in the "`squid` workaround" case).